# Magento2 add submenu in the top navigation menu

Tags: magento2, menu

I need to add submenu in top navigation menu

I am using below code but it is adding in top & not sub menu.

```
$menu = $observer->getMenu();
        $tree = $menu->getTree();
        $data = [
            'name'      => __('Menu item label here'),
            'id'        => 'some-unique-id-here',
            'url'       => 'url goes here',
            'has_active' => false,
            'is_active' => false //
        ];

        $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        foreach ($menu->getChildren() as $node) {
            if ($node->getName() == 'Carpet') {
                // echo "<pre>";
                // print_r($node->getId());
            }
        }
        //die();
        
        
        $menu->addChild($node);
        return $this;
```

I want to add submenu based on condition like for 1 top menu category I want to add 1 link e.g.  color & 2nd link in another top menu category e.g. size

I have a category top navigation menu by default of magento. Now I need to add color filter for each menu item.

For e.g. Shoes is the main menu & when we hover shoes it should display colors like White, black etc.. & on click of white I want to add redirection URL of filter. So in short white will be like a submenu

Comment: Specify your requirement in details.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have added more details.

Comment: codes looks ok i think there could be an issue with layout files

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension

https://github.com/faranaky/magento2-simple-menu

I think this should satisfy your requirement as it provides a feature to add Mega Menu with navigation type as product's attribute